# Not able to solve this data update issue in mvc5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I am unable to solve this error

[image]

it seems data update issue. how to resolve it?

result controller :

```
> using E_voting.Models.DataContext; using System; using
> System.Collections.Generic; using System.Linq; using System.Web; using
> System.Web.Mvc;
> 
> namespace E_voting.Controllers {
>     public class ResultController : Controller
>     {
>         private EvotingDBContext db = new EvotingDBContext();
>         // GET: Result
>         public ActionResult Index() {
>             db.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
>           
>             Dictionary<string, int> counts = new Dictionary<string, int>();
>             foreach (var item in db.Result.ToList())
>             {
>                 string id = item.CandidateId.ToString();
>                 KeyValuePair<string, int> temp = new KeyValuePair<string, int>(id.ToString(), 1);
>               if (counts.ContainsKey(id.ToString()))
>                {
>                   int index = Array.IndexOf(counts.Keys.ToArray(), id.ToString());
> 
> 
> 
>                 counts[id.ToString()] = counts[id.ToString()] + 1;
>                }
>                else
>                   counts.Add(id.ToString(), 1);
>          }
> 
>             int v = counts.Values.Max();
>             int tempmax = v;
>             string tempkey = "";
>            foreach (var item in counts)
>             {
>                if (item.Value == tempmax)
>                 {
>                     tempkey = item.Key;
>                     break;
>                 }
>             }
>             string tempname = "a";
>             foreach (var item in db.Candidate)
>             {
>                 if (item.CandidateId.ToString() == tempkey)
>                 {
>                     tempname = item.Name;
>                     break;
>                 }
>             }
>             ViewBag.winnerid = tempkey;
>             ViewBag.number = tempname;
>             ViewBag.winnercount = tempmax.ToString();
>             return View(db.Result.ToList());
>         }
> 
>         /*Count*/ //        Dictionary<string, int> counts = new Dictionary<string, int>(); //            foreach (var item in
> db.Result.ToList()) //            { //                int id =
> item.CandidateId; //        KeyValuePair<string, int> temp = new
> KeyValuePair<string, int>(id.ToString(), 1); //                if
> (counts.ContainsKey(id.ToString())) //                { //            
> int index = Array.IndexOf(counts.Keys.ToArray(), id.ToString());
> 
> //        counts[id.ToString()] = counts[id.ToString()] + 1; //       
> } //                else //                   
> counts.Add(id.ToString(), 1);                 //            } //      
> int tempmax = counts.Values.Max();
> 
>     } }
> 
>  
> 
> 
> > 
> > the above is the controller class and the error is in image .  this is
> > result model class :
> > 
> > using System; using System.Collections.Generic; using
> > System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations; using
> > System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema; using System.Linq; using
> > System.Web;
> > 
> > namespace E_voting.Models.Model {
> >    
> > 
> >      [Table("Result")]
> >       
> >     
> >         >   public class Result
> >         >     {
> >         >         [Key]
> >         >         public int VoteCastingId { get; set; }
> >
   >
```

> ```
>     >         public int CandidateId { get; set; }
>     > 
>     >         public int VoterId { get; set; }
>     >     } }
> ```

error image is also given if anyone guide me how to resolve this
it is showing ,system data entity infrastructure database update exception in result controller class.error image is also given if anyone **guide me how to resolve this
it is showing ,system data entity infrastructure database update exception in result controller class.**

Comment: Well the error tells that the update affected 0 rows. That should be quite clear description of the problem. And since you haven't provided any details... how can anyone else guess what's causing it?

Comment: Pls post your Result class, if you need to help you.

Comment: this is result class :

Comment: I do not see ````db.Result.Add````  from ToVote method

Answer (score 0):

You need to update, And in your case you append only and it's wrong because there is same object Id so you can before

```
db.Savechanges();
```

add
`db.Entry(YouResultClass).State=System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;`

Comment: or use    `AddOrUpdate()` Insted of    `Add()`